# Issue fetching xml elements c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <customUI onLoad="UI_Load" xmlns="somenamespace">
  <commands>
   <command id ="command1" onAction ="ExecuteCommand" />
  </commands>
 <ribbon>
  <tabs>
   <tab id="tab1">
    <group id="group1">
     ....
    </group>
    <group id="group2">
     ....
    </group>
    <group id="group3">
     ....
    </group>
    <group id="group4">
     ....
    </group>
   </tab>
  </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I load the xml from the assembly,

```
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var xml = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("mynamespace.myxml.xml");

    if (xml != null)
    {
     using (Stream stream = xml)
     {
        XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(stream);
        var elements = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("customUI/ribbon/tabs/tab/group");
     }
   }
```

`xdoc.XPathSelectElements("customUI/ribbon/tabs/tab/group")` returns nothing

I then `xdoc.Element("customUI")` returns null, I can view the xml elements in xdoc when I debug.

What am I doing wrong, why am I not able to view any child elements?

Comment: You're not using LINQ, do you want the solution to use LINQ? If not, why did you tag it?

Comment: @Bas you can use linq

Comment: You're missing the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the namespace:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", "somenamespace");
var t = xml.XPathSelectElements("/t:customUI/t:ribbon/t:tabs/t:tab/t:group", nsmgr);
```

You'll need `using System.Xml` at the top of the file to bring `XmlNamespaceManager` and `NameTable` into scope.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried what you have mentioned but it didn't fix my issue, still showing no elements

Comment: Weird. I copied your XML, run it and returns 4 elements. Are you sure your XML looks as you said it does?